# When attempting to update a self-hosted WordPress site, I'm seeing "ASN1 unknown message digest algorithm"

Tags: wp-admin, updates, windows

I've got several WordPress sites that I self-host on a Windows Server.

When attempting to perform the upgrade process, via `/wp-admin/update-core.php?action=do-core-upgrade` I see the following error:

> error:0D0890A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_verify:unknown message digest algorithm

It's entirely unclear to me where to begin resolving this issue.

Interestingly, the "WordPress News" applet shows a similar error:

> RSS Error: WP HTTP Error: Failure when receiving data from the peer
>
> RSS Error: WP HTTP Error: error:0D0890A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_verify:unknown message digest algorithm

Comment: I am not familiar with such but wanted just pointing out that google and/or [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)  could help you for this kind of  questions. It is a server problem and has nothing to do with WordPress. By doing some research you would have found [this?!](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cannot-update-my-wordpress-version) (read response made by Otto, follow links and do some research please)

Comment: Thanks, @Charles - I have searched and looked at quite a lot of pages that say Curl is the problem; however since this is a Windows server, I don't believe I even have Curl.  Also, I'm a high-rep user on the [dba.se] Stack site so I'm quite familiar with the SE Etiquette thing.  Thanks for your help, though!

Comment: What OpenSSL version are you running on? I have no idea how to query for installed packages on IIS servers, but there will be docs in the internets. FYI, I also reopened the question as this site is about *development and administration*.

Comment: another reference to lok at https://wordpress.org/support/topic/weird-error-unknown-message-digest-algorithm

Comment: This error is caused by your server having an outdated version of curl and/or the OpenSSL library.

Modern SSL certificates are signed using the SHA-256 algorithm, which your older code lacks support for. You need to update your server, or if you have a webhost, they need to update it for you.

Note that all older versions of OpenSSL are considered to be dangerously insecure, and you should be updating these in any case. If the webhost cannot update the server, then it's really time to find a new hosting service.

Answer (score 2):

@Kika is right that you have an older, insecure, version of OpenSSL.

This sounds like:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/getting-download-failed-error0d0890a1asn1-encoding-routinesfunc137reason

I wrote a small bit of code to skip the SSL test when trying to access the download server. It is not a good idea to use this code but will get you out of a pinch.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Skip SSL Verify
Plugin URI: http://www.damiencarbery.com
Description: Skip SSL verify in curl downloads - fixes: Download failed. error:0D0890A1:asn1 encoding routines:func(137):reason(161).
Author: Damien Carbery
Version: 0.1
*/

function ssv_skip_ssl_verify($ssl_verify) {
    return false;
}
add_filter('https_ssl_verify', 'ssv_skip_ssl_verify');
add_filter('https_local_ssl_verify', 'ssv_skip_ssl_verify');
```

Comment: small note, there is a core function called `return_false` which always returns false, intended to be used exactly for this kind of things.

Comment: @MarkKaplun: You're right. I prefer the longhand version so that I can add comments or even expand the function in the future (even though that's unlikely to happen in this code).